# Looping through procedure for each row result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure in mysql to loop into each row from query result. So i have this result query:

```
Person | Money1 | Money2
     A |    100 |    100
     B |    200 |    200
     C |    150 |    150
     D |    220 |    220
```

i want to compare each person money, the logic looks like this.

```
A with B
  Money1[A] --> Money1[B]
  Money2[A] --> Money2[B]
A with C
  Money1[A] --> Money1[C]
  Money2[A] --> Money2[C]
A with D
  Money1[A] --> Money1[D]
  Money2[A] --> Money2[D]
```

this is end for loop1 then continue..

```
B with C
  Money1[B] --> Money1[C]
  Money2[B] --> Money2[C]
B with D
  Money1[B] --> Money1[D]
  Money2[B] --> Money2[D]
```

this is end for loop2 and the last..

```
C with D
  Money1[C] --> Money1[D]
  Money2[C] --> Money2[D]
```

I have already function to compare the money, and it should be used like this:

```
SELECT compare(from_money1, from_money2, to_money1, to_money2);
```

so the result will looks like this :

```
Person | Result1 | Result2
    AB |    -100 |    -100
    AC |     -50 |     -50
    AD |    -120 |    -120
    BC |      50 |      50
    BD |     -20 |     -20
    CD |     -70 |     -70
```

But I am confused how to loop it from result query, can i do this on procedure mysql, it will be very helpfull if theres an example for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating things. This is all you need (given that the table name is money)

```
select concat(m1.person, m2.person) as Person, 
       m1.money1-m2.money1 as Result1, 
       m1.money2-m2.money2 as Result2 
  from money m1, 
       money m2 
 where m1.person < m2.person 
 order by m1.person, m2.person;
```